# Java: What happens in the memory?

Tags: java, memory, java.util.scanner

Example 1:

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
int x = input.nextInt();
if(x < value) {  }
```

Example 2:

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
if(input.nextInt() < value) {  }
```

I have two questions:

1. Which one is better to use if you *Only* need the value in that particular condition? Or both syntaxes are the same in terms of memory?
2. Whats happening to the entered value in the 2nd example in terms of memory?

Please I want the answers in detail.

Comment: For your last remark: just try to run the code and you know if you will have a syntax error.

Comment: @moffeltje Want I meant is that he couldn't answer my question. I know it runs perfectly.

Comment: Well, you actually only have access to the input in example 1, in example 2 the input is never saved, you only know that it is less than `value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The examples are the same in terms of memory because in both cases integer value is put into the stack. However, 1st approach is somewhat more convenient for debugging because you can easily observe the value and change it.
2. See prev. It's allocated in the stack.

Besides, local variables are recommended to start with lowercase, like this: `value`.

Comment: In this context stack is the area of program memory that holds the sequence of methods calls details and local variables. This is the basic concept of programming, and for good understanding I suggest reading some book for Java beginners, like Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel.